# PHP, ssh2_exec is not working properly

Tags: ssh, php, scripts

I have a shell script `makedir.sh` as given below.

```
sudo -H sh -c '
    mkdir /usr/local/testdir;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "Successfull";
    else
        echo "Unsuccessfull";
    fi
'
```

I have given privileges to a user testuser to execute shell script with sudo, but without asking password.For this I add the below line in `/etc/sudoers` file,

```
testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And it works fine that, I could run commands with sudo, but without asking password. The above shell script also working fine without asking password, creating directory `testdir` inside `/usr/local`. My problem starts here. I want to run this shell script from a `php` file. In the current scenario the shell script is residing in a remote machine with ip address 10.3.2.0. The following is my `php` code but, while running this php code, it is not creating any directory(testdir) inside `/usr/local/` . Please advise as I am very beginner in `PHP`.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("10.3.2.0", "22")))
{
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection";
}
else
{
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "testuser", "abcdef"))
    {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate ";
    }
    else
    {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($con, "./makedir.sh");
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $item = "";
        while ($input = fread($stream,4096)) {
               $item .= $input;
        }
        echo $item;
    }
}

?>
```

**SHELL SCRIPT - `makedir.sh` (residing at 10.3.2.0 - the same above shell script)**

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -H sh -c '
    mkdir /usr/local/testdir;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "Successfull";
    else
        echo "Unsuccessfull";
    fi
'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some part of shell script is there.

Comment: Well, you said that the shell script it works fine. I think that your problem is on this line: `ssh2_exec($con, "./makedir.sh")`. You should give the full path for the script.

Comment: I gave full path, but still is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), is generally better than libssh2. Better at diagnostics and reliability too. In your case... I'd try this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('./makedir.sh');

echo $ssh->getLog();
?>
```

And see what it says.

Comment: Now it is getting error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` while running php script from terminal as `php test.php`